# Lenovo trackpoint device not recognized

Tags: xubuntu, lenovo, trackpoint

I'm using Xubuntu 15.10 on a Lenovo Thinkpad Twist (S230u).

Unfortunately, the trackpoint device (the red stick between the g/h/b keys replacing the mouse) is not recognized by Ubuntu - most of the time.

Every once in a while the device works just perfectly. When this happens, there is an entry under

```
Settings / Mouse and Touchpad / Device : **TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint**
```

But after the next reboot this entry will have disappeared and the device won't work.

Does anyone have an idea what causes this strange behavior ?

Thanks !

Comment: Please, test if it's reproducible with [latest kernel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade), and if it is, report a bug. It would also help if you post either positive results or the bugreport URL here, so other users could see it.